# In Android is this a good and easy way to only have one Service running

Tags: android, service

I have this `Service` started from two locations in my code.

If the `Service` is inside the `onStartCommand()` and another

`startService` is made to start it again i need to stop it.

In the code below i set the  `private boolean getFriendListRunning;`

is this ok or what should i do?

```
public class ServiceGetFriendList  extends Service{

    private final String TAG = "ServiceGetFriendList";  
    private IBinder mBinder;
    private boolean failed = false;

    private boolean getFriendListRunning;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(getFriendListRunning)
            return Service.START_STICKY;

        getFriendListRunning = true;

        try{
           work......
           } catch (Exception e) {

          }finally{

          getFriendListRunning = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `IntentService` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html ? An IntentService 'lies dormant' until it recieves work to do via an Intent. If it recieves more than one Intent it queues them and processes one at a time in order of reception. When it has done all work it shuts down again.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I know IntentService and dont want to queue the calls. I want to kill the calls if one Service is already running inside the onStartCommand.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, however, it is probably better to re-design your implementation to avoid this use case (two locations start the same service), instead of doing the conditional check every time your activities trying to start a service at run time.

Comment: ended up using IntentService and before starting it i  check RunningServiceInfo to see if its already running, and not start it if its running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using IntentService and before starting it I check RunningServiceInfo to see if its already running, and not start it if its running

```
private boolean isIntentServiceRunning(String serv) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serv.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```